# Update Entity through a new Object in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I'd like to update an entity via linq, but since I edit the entity in a view after serializing it, I don't have direct access to the entity inside the data context. I could do it like this:

```
entity.property1 = obj.property1;
entity.property2 = obj.property2;
...
```

thats not cool... not cool at all.

Next thing I tried is to do it via .attach() like so:

```
context.Table.attach(entity, obj);
```

doesn't work either. So is there another option short of reflection?

Comment: What happened with the "attach" case?

Comment: Well in this case, I'd have do detach the entity, which I think really isn't the way it should be used. Since there is no detach method (http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2007/11/21/linq-to-sql-table-lt-t-gt-detach-method-does-not-exist.aspx), I actually don't know how I could attach something. There's a way (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/linq-to-sql-detach.aspx) but frankly I don't like tinkering on the model. I guess the easiest way to achieve what I want is to use reflection after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Attach() is not working because  the entity is still attached to the DataContext. Have you considered creating a new instance of your DataContext for when you reattach your entity? It is generally recommended not to have long-lived DataContexts, instead you should create a new instance per unit of work. This is because as long as you keep a DataContext instance in memory, all of the entities you have retrieved from it remain in memory as well (assuming ObjectTracking is enabled).

From MSDN:

> In general, a DataContext instance is
>   designed to last for one "unit of
>   work" however your application defines
>   that term. A DataContext is
>   lightweight and is not expensive to
>   create. A typical LINQ to SQL
>   application creates DataContext
>   instances at method scope or as a
>   member of short-lived classes that
>   represent a logical set of related
>   database operations.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.aspx

Comment: I used recursion after all, but your answer is sound :-) thanks